# iOS Push Notifications Message

Tags: ios, push-notification, nsdictionary

I want to display a push notifications message in an AlertView.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    NSDictionary *dic = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString *message = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Sie haben eine eine Nachricht." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

That's what `userInfo` variable contains:

[image]

I have tried this but `*message` is `nil`.

`NSString *message = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];`

How can I get the `"alert"` value? Any ideas?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you needed:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSString *message = [dic objectForKey:@"alert"];
```

Comment: No worries, it's good that you took the time to write a detailed description :)

Answer (score 1):

Using modern syntax, this should get you what you want. The 'alert' value is inside the 'aps' dictionary.

```
NSString *message = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"]
```